# How to cancel issued challenge in game centre

Tags: ios, game-center

I am stuck with iOS 7 Game Centre challenge integration, all I want is to get a notification when challenged player declines the challenge. But it seems that there is no callback when challenge is declined. Currently there are four notifications for a player who issued a challenge:

1. `- (void)localPlayerDidSelectChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge`
2. `- (void)localPlayerDidReceiveChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge`
3. `- (void)localPlayerDidCompleteChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge`
4. `- (void)remotePlayerDidCompleteChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge`

Just want to know, is there any way of getting a notification when challenged player declines a challenge?